# My link for selected text doesn't work in this post

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

This is a demonstration of a post that does not render properly (the lack of hyperlink):

```
code
code
code
```

text text [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html).
more text.

```
...stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this:

```
[logging module][1] (http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)
```

You'll want to drop that `[1]` and go with this:

```
[logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)
```

To get this:

> [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

Comment: That's a red herring.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like markdown doesn't want to parse links in a block immediately preceding a section surrounded by <pre> tags. Your [foo][1](http://null.com) label with footnote looks fine, and inserting one with the hyperlink WYSIWYG tool generates the same format (which also doesn't work).

I noticed you used <code> and <pre> tags -- it's generally easier to just indent your text by four spaces (which the binary button at the top of the editing window will do for you).

```
text using code and pre tags
```

Here is a [link](http://null.com) that does not work... through experimentation, it would seem that it is the <pre> tag following that screws things up.

```
...stuff inside a pre tag
```

```
text using four spaces of indentation
```

Here is a [link](http://null.com) that does work.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do this!"

Comment: @Jeff: so you're saying that <pre> and <code> tags are invalid markdown syntax? That was not at all clear...

Answer (score 0):

From what I see of your raw post text, you have not used valid Markdown.

Please refer to the [editing help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), which is linked:

- in the little [?] icon above the edit area
- in the sidebar under full reference »

Comment: Incorrect. See my post for another reproduction of this issue.

Comment: it is in fact correct; indent 4 spaces instead of hard coding <pre><code> -- problem solved.

Comment: But all I did was select the text and use the "add link" feature, I didn't write this markdown syntax myself so how can it be my fault?